# C++ std::string to number template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std, stdstring

I am currently trying to implement my own standard input reader for personal use. I have created a method to read an integer from standard input and do some checks on its validity. The idea is that I read a string from the standard input, do several checks, convert to int, do last checks, return the value that has been read. If any error happens meanwhile the checks I will just fill an `errorHint` to print on `std::cerr` and return `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`.

I think the idea is quite simple and straightforward to implement, now I wanted to generalize the concept and make the method template, so basically I could chose at compile time, whenever I need to read from the standard input which type of integer I want (it could be `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned long` and so on but an integer). In order to do so I have created the following static template method:

```
template<
    class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
> 
static T getIntegerTest(std::string& strErrorHint,
                        T nMinimumValue = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),
                        T nMaximumValue = std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
```

and the implementation in the same .hpp file few lines below:

```
template<
    class T,
    class>
T InputReader::getIntegerTest(std::string& strErrorHint,
                              T nMinimumValue,
                              T nMaximumValue)
{
    std::string strInputString;
    std::cin >> strInputString;

    // Do several checks

    T nReturnValue = std::stoi(strInputString); /// <--- HERE!!!

    // Do other checks on the returnValue

    return nReturnValue;
}
```

Now the problem is, I want to convert the string that I just read and that I know is within the correct range to the integer type `T`. How can I do this in a good way?

Comment: `bool success = std::cin >> T_instance;`, then (another) range check...

Comment: Why no simply use `std::istringstream`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specialising a function object is a very versatile way to modify behaviour based on type traits.

The approach is:

1. define a general template for the operation
2. specialise the template for corner cases
3. call through a helper function

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>


namespace detail {
/// general case
    template<class Integer, typename Enable = void>
    struct convert_to_integer {
        Integer operator()(std::string const &str) const {
            return std::stoi(str);
        }
    };

// special cases
    template<class Integer>
    struct convert_to_integer<Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<long, Integer>::value> > {
        long operator()(std::string const &str) const {
            return std::stol(str);
        }
    };
}

template<class T, class StringLike>
T to_integral(StringLike&& str)
{
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
    return detail::convert_to_integer<type>()(str);
};

int main() {

    std::string t1 = "6";
    const char t2[] = "7";

    std::cout << to_integral<int>(t1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_integral<int>(t2) << std::endl;

    // will use the specilaisation
    std::cout << to_integral<long>(t1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_integral<long>(t2) << std::endl;

    // will use the default case
    std::cout << to_integral<short>(t1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_integral<short>(t2) << std::endl;
}
```

p.s. your error reporting strategy needs work. Suggest throwing a `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Richard Hodges ! Very nice! I do appreciate a lot! For the exception why do you think it is better to throw an exception rather than using an errorHint? In particular I guess you would suggest to create my own error type and throw that one in case of failure is that correct?

Comment: @user2271691 ideally your own error type, derived from std::runtime_error or from std::invalid_argument.